# How Do I Dynamically (based on server env) Choose Which Database My Kohana ORM Connects To?

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3.2

This is for Kohana v3.2

How can I dynamically choose the database an ORM model connects to? Specifically, I am trying to change an ORM model to work with databases in my local dev, staging and production environments.

The [Kohana Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/models) tells me I can set the database connection by setting a protected property on the ORM model like this:

```
class Model_Customer extends ORM
{
    protected $_db_group = 'local_db';
    protected $_table_name = 'customer';
```

This works fine when developing locally, but what about when I move to stage and then production? I'd rather not have to change the _db_group each time I change environments. I can check server vars to determine environment, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to dynamically set the db_group property to match the environment since I can't do any logic in a class definition.

There's probably a better way to approach this problem that I'm hoping someone will be able to suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Don't do this by $_db_group but on different env make different `config/database.php`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, check the connection in your `database.php` config file.

```
return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'MySQL',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for MySQL:
             *
             * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
             * string   database     database name
             * string   username     database username
             * string   password     database password
             * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
             * array    variables    system variables as "key => value" pairs
             *
             * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
             */
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'database'   => (Kohana::$environment == Kohana::DEVELOPMENT) ? 'local_db' : 'kohana',
            'username'   => FALSE,
            'password'   => FALSE,
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
    ),
);
```

Comment: I highly doubt that a configuration file is the correct place for logic. However, it should be easy to create an `ORM` child that in it's constructor chooses the correct db connection (and future models extend that child).

Comment: It is the easiest way. There is no framework solution to separate develop and production environment in Kohana (imo).

Comment: I meant setting `$_db_group` based on the logic you present here. But you showed how it can be done, so I'm removing the -1

Comment: @kingkero, can you elaborate a little on your idea? I will look at mobal's solution too.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment to [mobal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861393/1557526), I'd take a slightly different approach while using the same logic.

You can see in the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/config#example) that it is possible to have multiple db configs. In this case it could look like this

```
return array(
    'default' => array( /* regular connection */ ),
    Kohana::DEVELOPMENT => array( /* connection for development */ )
);
```

Now the question is: Where should the logic be put that decides which connection is used? First I thought the `ORM` class would be a good place - but actually I doubt that. A model shouldn't concern, which connection is used.

However, [`Database::instance()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database#instance) looks right. This is the method that determins which configuration will be used. And so changing it here will effect everything that uses a database - so the perfect place.

Since Kohana uses wrapper classes, you can create a file `APPPATH/classes/Database.php` and add your changes there like this

```
class Database extends Kohana_Database {

    public static function instance($name = NULL, $config = NULL) {
        if ($name === NULL && Kohana::$environment == Kohana::DEVELOPMENT) {
            $name = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT;
        }
        return parent::instance($name, $config);
    }

}
```

Now whenever you try to get the default instance (which is the case in ORM if no `_db_group` is set) **and** are in the development environment, the development config will be used for connecting to your database.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for the ideas.

My use case involves working with a database config file which references 6 different databases (2 databases times 3 environments for each of those).

For my specific case, this was the simplest solution I could come with without worry of possibly fouling up DB connections in other areas of the app

Pseudo code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'staging.acme.com')
    {
        $this->_db_group = 'db1_stage';
    }
    else if ($_SERVER['KOHANA_ENV'] == 'development')
    {
        $this->_db_group = 'db1_local';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_db_group = 'db1_production';
    }

    parent::__construct();
}
```

This sets the `$_db_group` property before calling `parent::construct()` which initializes the database connection for the ORM using the DB I need.

Comment: May I ask why you decided to use this and not the solution I provided?

Comment: Yes, mainly because I wasn't confident enough to implement that change and not worry that I would break something elsewhere in the app.

Comment: this solution move config outside config... Better make this `in config/database.php` (if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'staging.acme.com') return Array(...)). Or not add `in config/database.php` to project. Add `in config/database.default.php`, and on any env set right values.